# Can i receive signal from an arduino board and read it throug a java program?

Tags: java, arduino

I want to control a few stepper motors with my arduino board. I have created a simple program to do that. But now I want to send some information through my pc through a java software on real time ( for eg stepper motor 1 should conplete 3 revolutions and then only stepper motor should start like that) but now the java program is sending all the information together but i want it to send only when the current movement is executed. So is there any way that my arduino board say to my pc that ok now send me next set of data or like that and my java program would read it and do the needful? The whole communication preferably occur using the usb.

I am jst a begginer this my first project i am learning the whole thing using net. So if u can suggest some tutorial it will also be okay.
Thanking in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do some **research** and find out the answers by going through the following **resources**.
This might be what you are looking for:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N30jHMhw9c](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtyOiTw0oQc)

If you want to **wait** for some time to execute the next instructions, you can try using https://www.javatpoint.com/sleep()-method

You can always **send an interrupt** using the method:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtyOiTw0oQc

I hope this would be of some help!

Comment: Actually i want the java code on my pc to wait for unspecified time until the arduino reaponds. I dont want the aeduino to wait.

Comment: Have you tried using the method in the youtube tutorial on how to send an interrupt, after sending an interrupt you can always read that via code.